# SQL query - Limit results if no match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Background:

This is a query for searching a db full of products and the SQL is built on the fly depending on what the user has searched.

```
SELECT *

FROM gifts 

LEFT JOIN tags_gifts ON tags_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id 

LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_gifts.tag_id 

WHERE published = '1'
AND ( (tags_gifts.tag_id = '887') ) 

GROUP BY gifts.gift_id 

ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC , gift_popularity DESC
```

This is working as planned however the next part I am trying to do I am struggling with.

I have another table '**tags_gifts_occasion_specific**' which has columns of '**gift_id**' and '**tag_id**'

Basically if a user searches like the above but there is no tag_id to search for or the tag_id they have searched for does not match the one in tags_gifts_occasion_specific.tag_id then I want to exclude those results.

Do I need to do another select statement inside this one to achieve this? Hope this makes sense

Comment: Can you clarify your question ? What's the purpose of tags_gifts_occasion_specific ?

Comment: Sorry - that table is used to store gift_id's that can only appear in search results if the tag used to find them matches the tag searched. Eg. If somebody searches but doesn't enter a tag(keyword) then the product will not appear. However if they search 'mothers day' which matches the tag then the items will appear. This allows products relating to special days to be ignored from generic searches eg 'red'. The user searching 'red' will not see any 'mothers day' gifts even if they match 'red' too

Comment: Is there another way to search (apart with a tag_id) ?

Comment: Yes. The tag_id can be blank, in which case all results will show. If a keyword is entered but cannot be matched to a defined 'tag' then a MATCH AGAINST is used on the product title instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved in the end by doing the following:

```
 AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tags_gifts_occasion_specific WHERE tags_gifts_occasion_specific.gift_id = gifts.gift_id)
```

Then for searches where tags have been included:

```
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tags_gifts_occasion_specific WHERE tags_gifts_occasion_specific.gift_id = gifts.gift_id AND tags_gifts_occasion_specific.tag_id != '971' )
```

Thanks okio for your help - it was your answer which led me in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM gifts AS g
    LEFT JOIN tags_gifts_occasion_specific AS os ON g.gift_id = os.gift_id
    LEFT JOIN tags_gifts ON tags_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id 
    LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_gifts.tag_id 

WHERE published = '1'
    AND (os.tag_id IS NULL OR os.tag_id = '887')
    AND tags_gifts.tag_id = '887'

GROUP BY gifts.gift_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC , gift_popularity DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It is working for searches where no keywords have been entered, but doesn't when a keyword has been searched. The SQL below is a search for 'candle(971)' but 'wedding' tags need to be excluded. All this does is show the ones I want excluding: SELECT * FROM gifts 
LEFT JOIN tags_gifts_occasion_specific AS os ON gifts.gift_id = os.gift_id 
LEFT JOIN tags_gifts ON tags_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id 
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_gifts.tag_id 
WHERE published = '1' 
AND ( (tags_gifts.tag_id = '971') ) 
AND ( os.tag_id = '576' OR os.tag_id = '1689' ) 
GROUP BY gifts.gift_id